# Check if letter 1 is always followed by number 2 and number 2 by number 3

Tags: java, string

I want to write a function that return true if if and only if 
String a is always followed by String b, and String b is always followed by string c, this is what I wrote but it doesn't work :

```
public static boolean follows2(String s, String a, String b, String c) {
    boolean res = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (charAtPos(s, i).equals(a)) {

            if (!(charAtPos(s, i + 1).equals(b))) {
                res = false;
                if (!(charAtPos(s, i + 2).equals(c))) {
                    res = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(follows2(" koali oliali ", "a", "l", "i"));
    // RETURN TRUE OK since for each " a" is followed by "l" then "i"
    System.out.println(follows2("ipoipa", "i", "p", "a"));
    //RETURN TRUE BUT IT'S NOT !
    // The first " i" is followed by " p" then "o" which is not good 
}
```

Here is the function that I wrote for:
String a is always followed by String b ( It works )

```
public static boolean follows(String s, String a, String b) {
    boolean res = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (charAtPos(s, i).equals(a)) {

            if (!(charAtPos(s, i + 1).equals(b))) {
                res = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public static String charAtPos(String s, int i) {
    return String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(follows("Arnold Barney", "r", "n"));
    // RETURN TRUE because each "r" are followed by the letter "n"
    System.out.println(follows("Arnold Barney", "n", "o"));
    // RETURN FALSE , because not every "n" is followed by "o"
}
```

What can be done in my first program to make it work ?
Thank you

Comment: You need to debug your program, find the problem and fix it.

Comment: or post a question on Stackoverflow...what?...wait!

Comment: If you `return false` instead of setting `res = false` the problem will be more obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are not actually entering the nested `if` statements due to a minor flaw in your logic.

I would change it to this which checks whether `i + 1 is equal to String b || i + 2 is equal to String c`

```
public static boolean follows2(String s, String a, String b, String c) {
        boolean res = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (charAtPos(s, i).equals(a)) {
                if (!(charAtPos(s, i + 1).equals(b)) || !(charAtPos(s, i + 2).equals(c))) {
                    res = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer I've been looking for
I just started java at school , solutions suggested by other were too difficult for me too understand

Comment: I would check them out though, they could greatly improve your understanding of Java.

Comment: This works nicely as long as your are lucky enough to have strings (a, b, c) with `.length()` == `1`. This returns `false`: `System.out.println(follows("Arnold", "n", "ol", "d"));`

Comment: @Stefan OP is using `char` so I assumed that the input would always be single characters. I also just tried to make the answer as close to the original attempt as possible.

Answer (score 1):

With recursion:

```
public static boolean follows(String s, String a, String b, String c) {
    int ai = s.indexOf(a);
    if (ai == -1) {
        return true; // No more 'a' string, we're all good
    }
    int bi = s.indexOf(a + b);
    int ci = s.indexOf(a + b + c);
    if (bi != ai || ci != ai) {
        return false; // Strings 'b' and 'bc' don't follow 'a', so the check failed
    }
    return follows(s.substring(ai + a.length()), a, b, c);
}
```

In reality, `bi` could be removed.

Comment: Nice tidy answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much cleaner answer (tested & working great):

```
public static boolean follows(String s, String...strings) {
    int number = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if(strings[number].length()+i<s.length() && s.substring(i, strings[number].length()+i).equals(strings[number]) && number+1 != strings.length) number++;
        else if(number!=0 && !s.substring(i, strings[number].length()+i).equals(strings[number])) return false;
        else number = 0;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It fixes many problems with your code:

- Working with strings but using "charAt"
- Copying the function just to add a parameter

Comment: `follows("123", "1", "2", "3")` returns false... (and you need to add a ")" to make it compile)

Comment: Woops, made a mistake there. It's fixed now and works. That what happens when you do not test your code ;).

Comment: Did you try the examples in the original question? (" koali oliali " and "ipoipa")

Comment: Strange, I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. My bad, probably, sorry to bother you with this.

Comment: Almost :) Now `follows("Arnold Barney", "n", "o")` returns `true`. Everything else is good.

Comment: Wow, I messed up again. Now it should work... edit: now

Answer (score 0):

Because the code doesn't do what you think it does.

**if you'll add some prints to the code**, you'll see you never set "res" to false.

Let's debug the case you're testing:

- When meet the the first letter - "i" - it entered the first if.
- the next letter is "p" so you're not entered the 2nd if, so you'll continue to the next letter in the "for".

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt (haven't tested it)

```
boolean hasOnlyCompleteSequences(String source, char.. chars) {
    for (int s = 0; s < source.length(); s++) {
       int c = 0;
       if (source.charAt(s) == chars[c]) {
           if (!isCompleteSequence(source, s + 1, chars, c + 1)) {
               return false;
           }
       }          
    }
    return true;
}

boolean isCompleteSequence(String source, int s, char[] chars, int c) {
    while (s < source.length() && c < chars.length) {
        // note: the indices get increased AFTER comparison
        if (source.charAt(s++) != chars[c++]) {
            return false;
        }            
    }
    // cover the case that the source String ends with an incomplete sequence
    if (s == source.length() && c < chars.length) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```